# Apache Reverse Proxy with Frontend and Backend Authentication

Tags: apache, authentication, reverse-proxy, kerberos

Here's the outcome I am trying to achieve:

1. Client browser (Chrome in my case) hits the Apache HTTPd server (server1) on 50070. The client browser has no access to Kerberos KDC and carries no Kerberos/GSS auth data.
2. Apache HTTPd has access to KDC and is configured to require Kerberos authentication, but with a password fallback (i.e. `KrbMethodK5Passwd` is `On`, so it accepts "`Authorization: Basic`" in HTTP headers).
3. Client browser prompts user for login and password thanks to the fallback option (as there's no Kerberos ticket offered by client). Apache HTTPd validates supplied login and password against Kerberos, and obtains the correct user principal Kerberos ticket and keeps that in memory (it also saves it to /tmp, thanks to `KrbSaveCredentials` option).
4. Apache HTTPd reverse-proxies to a backend server (server2), which also listens on port 50070. The backend server is running Jetty, which accepts Kerberos only, without any password/Basic authentication fallback - if there's no Kerberos ticket, there's no entry. Apache HTTPd sends the user principal Kerberos ticket obtained from KDC using login+pass to server2.

In my current configuration, points 1, 2 & 3 work successfully - i.e. the client to server1 authentication works correctly and I can see Apache saving the user principal ticket on server1 for a brief moment.

However, I'm having difficulty forcing Apache HTTPd to use the obtained user Kerberos ticket to authenticate with server2. Basically no authentication detail is sent at all to server2.

Here's my configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:50070>
  ServerAlias server1.example.com:50070
  ServerAlias server1:50070
  ProxyPreserveHost Off
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass / http://server2.example.com:50070/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse / http://server2.example.com:50070/ retry=0
  <Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ErrorLog logs/error_log
  TransferLog logs/access_log
  LogLevel debug
  <Location />
    Options None
    AuthType Kerberos
    AuthName "NameNode"
    KrbMethodNegotiate on
    KrbMethodK5Passwd on
    KrbServiceName HTTP
    KrbAuthRealms EXAMPLE.COM
    Krb5Keytab /etc/httpd/conf/http.keytab
    KrbSaveCredentials on
    KrbLocalUserMapping on
    Require valid-user
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also tried using `SetEnv proxy-chain-auth` offered by `mod_proxy_http`, which I suppose works as designed, it does indeed send the exact content of "`Authorization: Basic ...`" header that client came to server1 with, onward to server2, but server2 does not support anything but Kerberos (i.e. "`Authorization: Negotiate`"), and complains about unknown auth method in its logs.

Is there a way to force Apache HTTPd to use the Kerberos ticket obtained from KDC, using the login and password provided by client browser, to then authenticate using Negotiate method (with ticket) with the target server2 I'm reverse proxying to?

Comment: Have you by any chance been successful. I'm trying to achieve this as well.